# 'that soon' instead of 'how soon' is correct?

Tags: adjectives

I know about this expression: "it's not that bad!" It means it's not too bad.

Now my question is: can we used 'that' before other adjectives or adverbs?
I want to use it in the following sentence:

> In the train, everyone slept early at night but I didn't use to sleep that soon.

Please, tell me is that correct?

Comment: The *didn't use to* part sounds really odd to me. It took me to think "if this is really grammatical?" for a while, before I saw that it could be. However, I think *"I never used to sleep that soon"* or *"I'm not used to sleep that soon"* might sound better. (Though they sound close, they don't have the same meaning.)

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the [basic meanings of 'that'](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/that_5):

> **that** *adverb* /ðæt/ B2. as much as suggested

Thus, one would say something like

> On the train everyone went to bed around 20:00, but I wasn't used to sleeping that early.

*That* (and *this*), *so*, and *how* can all be used as adverbs of degree, but only *that* or *so* would be used here; *how* is typically used when the degree is unknown, e.g. *I didn't know how early we would sleep*.